# How set value of existing product attribute in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

My every product in WooCommerce has several attributes. One of them is named `my-availability` and I need to change its value dynamically depending on stock change and some condition logic. So when the amount of pieces on stock is changed (usually decreased by order), the value of `my-availability` attribute will change. It should not add any new attributes, just change the value of the existing one. I do not use product variations at all.
I am total beginner and trying to build this piece of code for few days using a lot of googling. Now I have something like this:

```
function changeatt( $order ) 
 {
  $items = $order->get_items();
  
  foreach( $items as $item ) {
    $value2 = get_field( "naceste", $item['product_id']);  //need to get value of custom field "naceste"
    $value = get_post_meta( $item['product_id'], '_stock', true );   //need to get how many pcs is on stock
   
    if ($value == 0 && $value2 > 0)
     {$avl = 'Coming soon';}

    if ($value == 0 && $value2 == 0)
      { $avl = 'Not in stock';}

    if ($value > 0)
      { $avl = 'In stock';}
      
     // update_post_meta( $item['product_id'], 'my-availability', $avl ); 
  wp_set_object_terms( $item['product_id'], $avl, 'pa_my-availability', false);
  }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_reduce_order_stock', changeatt );
```

This code actually creates new custom field `my-availability` with the correct value, but I need to save it to existing attribute named `my-availability` instead. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found it! `update_post_meta` did not work for changing attributes, do not know why.  `wp_set_object_terms` must be used instead and `pa_` must be added to the name of the attribute. I have edited the code in the question to the working version. The previous not-working line has been removed by `//` for other beginners, who will be solving the same situation to learn from this one. It took me few days to solve this.
Now I am pretty curious, how to find out, which types of variables can be changed using `update_post_meta` and which types using `wp_set_object_terms`.